# what could prevent GetPixel from working?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using GetPixel to read pixels from a certain window (to be more specific, a poker table).

Now, of course, on my PC, and just about 95% of other PC, it all works swell. But every now and then, there is a PC where this does not work - GetPixel returns CLR_INVALID. Even though the OS is win7 with aero turned on (i've seen it happen only on win7 64-bit).

So, the same window - using GetPixel works on my PC, but it does not work on the other PC.

Has anyone encountered this before? Can some application prevent other apps. from using GetPixel?

Answer (score 0):

If the other application is running elevated, or is running as another user, you won't be able to touch it.

Comment: Hmmm i see... What if I'm running elevated as well?

Comment: Update: that does not seem to be the case - I just tried running the poker client as Administrator, and me, as a regular user - it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If the pixel is outside of the current
>   clipping region, the return value is
>   `CLR_INVALID`.

Comment: I see... As a side note, if I capture the whole window, and I do a BitBlt, it works. What am I to make of that?

Comment: That you are sampling a pixel outside of the clipping range of the DC associated with the window. You can still BitBlt, since that is doing a bulk operation on the entire DC.